Powering on a laser diode that exceeds PSU max current
I have a laser diode that I want to test (just seeing if it turns on). However, the threshold current is past the 10A that my bench power supply can supply, hence I can't generate any light. How can I supply a higher current, say 20A, using basic electronics parts that I may have lying around?

What is the power of the laser?  At 20A it's going to be significant.  Do you have the datasheet for the laser?  Is it visible light?  It's worth stressing you must make sure you have adequate optical and fire safety in place.  Using an experimental circuit means you simply don't know if the laser is going to come on, and experimenting with a class 4 laser is inherently risky.  Even diffused reflections might be well above safety limits.  In literally less than the blink of an eye.

@DrMoishePippik Thanks, I tested it and it works. Although at the capacitance where my camera picks it up, a basic THT resistor gets destroyed.

@jonathanjo This is a 30W bar diode @ 808nm. I don't have the datasheet.

@DrMoishePippik - Hi, Thanks for trying to help. However please don't answer in a comment. That is not one of the (deliberately few) allowed uses of comments. Please see here for why answering in a comment can be harmful & here for more details of the allowed uses of comments. || Therefore please consider moving that comment into an actual answer. TY

For anybody reading this later: An 808 nm laser is invisible to the eye; at 30 W it will exceed the permitted radiation in a small fraction of a microsecond. Even diffused, divergent or reflections can blind or burn you.  Do not experiment with such lasers unless you are certain you are competent to safely contain the energy.  At my lab we had a picture of Daffy Duck on the wall, looking down the barrel of a gun wondering if it worked, and a picture of the retina of our laser safety trainer.

Edit: See also comment by DrMoishe Pippik
If pulsed operation is fine (as it is here), you can get away with a capacitor, inductor, Power MOSFET and a signal generator. The idea is to convert the 10A average current into 20A pulsed current.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here the current source + resistor represent your PSU.
Most cheap PSUs are not true constant current sources, so a large inductor is added to smoothen the current. Now, because the capacitor has infinite DC impedance, the DC current trough the diode must be the 10 amps supplied by the PSU.
When the MOSFET is off, zero current flows trough the diode. This allows us to multiply the input current by controlling the duty cycle of the frequency source. For example, with 50% duty cycle, the average on-current will be 20A. In general, the average ON-current is \$I_{ON}=\frac{I_{PSU}}{D}\$ where \$D\$ is the duty cycle.
Finally, it should be noted that typically connecting a voltage source such as a capacitor directly to a (laser) diode causes a large inrush current, potentially destroying the device. This is because the I-V curve of a diode is very steep, so even a small mismatch in voltage can cause a large excess current. However, due to the self-adjusting nature of this circuit, and the small enough ripple voltage across the capacitor, the laser can be operated safely. For less current ripple, you can make the capacitor larger, the PWM frequency faster, or add a resistor in series with the diode (my implementation of the cirucit had about 80mOhm of in-series resistance).
I should also note that the signal generator MUST be powered, before powering on the PSU. Additionally I recommend setting the output current (and voltage) to 0, then connecting the PSU, and then increasing the current gradually.
The current multiplying effect might also work without the external capacitor and inductor, as similar components are usually inside a PSU. However, I strongly recommend against doing so as it will cause unreliable operation and possibly damage the PSU. Of course, removing just the capacitor but keeping the inductor will cause the MOSFET to be immediately destroyed.

Far more elaborate than needed to answer question.

To make a quick test of that power laser diode, put a small resistor in series, and a moderate size capacitor across the output of the power supply.

In the diagram above, a 1µF cap charged to 10 or 20 V should provide a momentary pulse large enough to get the diode to turn on, and the 1 kΩ resistor limits current to 20 mA, safe for a diode rated at 10-20 A. The capacitor value can be increased somewhat if there is no detectable output from the laser.
Safety Warning:
A 10 or 20 A laser diode could immediately burn out part or all of the retina of an eye! Use proper safety precautions. An easy way to observe an IR laser, as well as a visible-light one, is with a webcam or camera, inside a light-tight enclosure. The unfiltered output might damage a sensor, but that is preferable to permanent eye damage.
